How to align << in source code that spans multiple lines
I have this problem with << unalignment in Visual Studio.
cout << "Spring" << endl
    << "Summer" << end
    << "Autumn" << endl
    << "Winter" << endl;

Every time I hit enter, the new line moves back 1 space compared to the cout line and the <<'s are not lining up. If I want to align it, I have to do it manually which is pretty annoying. Is there any way to do this automatically?

If you break the line between cout and the first << it will be much easier.

Have a look at std::format, and specifically Standard format specification this gives you a lot of control over the output formatting before sending it to std::cout (in C++23 you can even use std::print)

@PepijnKramer: I think OP problem is code formatting, not output formatting.

Which code formatter do you use? (clang-format?) I think default is to not align and just use extra tabulation (so 4 spaces in your case). You have to check option of your formatter.

For clang-format see AlignOperands

@Jarod42 A fair enough.

Older question, but without a good answer that leaves the first << on the same line as cout: Visual Studio 2019 align cout << operator. If someone could give an answer for this case over there, this one could be closed as a duplicate.

You can report a feature request on Developer Community and post report link here so that we can follow up.
